# Error in defining pyspark datastructure variables with a for loop

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to define a set of pyspark features as a run time variables (features).
I tried the below, it throws an error. Could you please help on this

```
colNames = ['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE']  
tsfresh_feature_set = StructType(
      [
        
        StructField('field1', StringType(), True),     
        StructField('field2', StringType(), True),        
        StructField(item, DoubleType(), False) for item in colNames
        
      ]
    )
```

Error that I get:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-621368>", line 9
    StructField(item, DoubleType(), False) for item in colNames
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use list comprehension for creating structure using list of column names for your DataFrame

```
StructField(item, DoubleType(), False) for item in colNames
```

But the problem is with the syntax:

1. Wrap your code with `[]`

```
[StructField(item, DoubleType(), False) for item in colNames]
```

2. Unwrap the elements inside the list using `*`

```
colNames = ['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE']  
tsfresh_feature_set = StructType(
      [        
        StructField('field1', StringType(), True),     
        StructField('field2', StringType(), True),
        *[StructField(item, DoubleType(), False) for item in colNames]
      ]
    )
```